# My magento website is not opening

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error

I got this error when I hit my website.

> There has been an error processing your request
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1030 Got error 28 from storage engine, query was: DESCRIBE `log_visitor_info`

and I am also unable to open Magento admin, inserted right username and password, but it remains on the same page. And I am also unable to open phpmyadmin.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See  [1030 Got error 28 from storage engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631387/1030-got-error-28-from-storage-engine)

Mysql error "28 from storage engine" - means "**not enough disk space**".

To show disc space use command below.

```
 myServer# df -h
```

Answer (score 1):

As per R.S Answer, your database is full.

It's a good idea to do Database maintenance with magento, which is just cleaning out the tables that build up quickly.

These tables are:

`log_customer log_visitor log_visitor_info log_url log_url_info log_quote report_viewed_product_index report_compared_product_index report_event catalog_compare_item`

You can run the following `php -f shell/log.php clean` which will get the log.php to run the script to clear these tables and help reduce your database size.

Disclaimer - Always make sure to backup anything before trying commands from the internet.

Comment: I am also unable to open phpmyadmin. how to clean these tables.

Comment: If you have SSH access to the server you can run the command from your magento directory